# mod_perl (2.0.x) on apache 2.2.x on Windows - abandoned?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, mod-perl

#### mod_perl2 on Windows?

It's sometimes beneficial (at least for me) to have a 
recent Apache http server plus mod_perl2 (and PHP) 
running on the development (desktop) box to try out
some ideas.

This was **straightforward until Perl version 5.10** where
you could simply install the win32 binary from apache.org,
install Activeperl 5.10, then install mod_perl2 via the 
Activestate-ppm installer and be done with it. Both Perl
and the httpd binary were VC6 (Visual C++ 6) builds,
mod_perl2 would get runtime-loaded without problems.

After Perl 5.10 (and after PHP 5.2.17), the situation
under windows got desperate. If I'm not mislead, you
**can't have** a simple httpd/**perl**/php development system
under Windows anymore. Why?

[Newer PHP builds](http://windows.php.net/download/) are *VC9 only* (build with Visual C++ 9) and
won't runtime-link to apache.org httpd binaries. There are
some folks ([apachelounge](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/) etc.) who build VC9-httpd binaries
which re-enables PHP development on windows.

But there are, if I'm correct, **no recent mod_perl binaries** 
neither for  VC9 builds (preferable) nor for VC6 builds - there aren't
any. After using mod_perl2 on windows for years and looking
for updates - I'm surprised.

Does somebody know how to get a windows install (32bit) containing
recent packages:

- httpd 2.2.21 (or higher)
- Perl 5.14.x + mod_perl 2.0.5 (or higher)
- PHP 5.3.8 (or higher)

Thanks in advance

rbo

Answer (score 0):

Here are three choices for getting this to work under Apache 2.2:

- Build them all yourself using the correct version of Visual Studio | Hard
- Download the src's from ActiveState and hope they have a win module for you as Apache recommends | Lucky
- Go with ActivePerl | Easy

Here's the link from Apache to ActiveState but doesn't work for me, maybe works for you.
ftp://ftp.activestate.com/ActivePerl/src/